# c# How can I directly compare the "base types" of generic classes?

Tags: c#, generics, types, compare

I want this check to succeed.

```
SerializableObject<GameObject> gameObject = new SerializableObject<GameObject>();
SerializableObject<Sprite> sprite = new SerializableObject<Sprite>();

// this is the check I want to have succeed,
// because both dog and cat share the SerializableObject generic type.
if (gameObject *has same base type as* sprite ) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Is there any way of doing this?

EDIT:
After feedback on the confusing usage of Animal for the type generics, let me change to my specific example instead.

Comment: question: what are you trying to achieve here ? if it is reading properties or executing methods of base class , simple statement like : var obj= dog as Base: cat.x=obj.x; should suffice.

Comment: "_Is there any way of doing this_" Yes, but this seems very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Your class-structure seems **very** odd. Why is `Animal` generic? Instead of generics you should use inheritance here, which is this: a `Dog` **is** an `Animal` and thus it should **derive** from it

Comment: Look at `Type.IsGenericType` and `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`.  The first will tell you that `dog.GetType()` is generic and the second will tell you that it's based on `Animal<T>`.  Like everyone else, I'm scratching my head at your example, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.  It checks that the types are generic and that the underlying generic type is the same:

```
public class GameObject { }
public class Sprite { }

public class SerializableObject<T> where T : class {}
```

And then check to see how they are related:

```
var game = new SerializableObject<GameObject>();
var sprite = new SerializableObject<Sprite>();

var typeGame = game.GetType();
var typeSprite = sprite.GetType();

if (typeGame.IsGenericType && typeSprite.IsGenericType &&
    typeGame.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeSprite.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(game)} and {nameof(sprite)} are related through {nameof(SerializableObject<T>)}");
}
```

You should see that the `WriteLine` statement executes

Comment: Straight to the point! But I agree, the usage of Animal, Dog and Cat was confusing since it is so commonly used for inheritance. Feel free to change it to something else like I did in my original post. If you do, I will accept your solution.

Comment: despite the fact that `nameof(SerializableObject<T>)` won´t compile, as `T` is not defined, you finally pinned OPs question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: That code compiles and runs.  The output of that `Debug.WriteLine` call is _"game and sprite are related through SerializableObject"_.  The `nameof` operator is pretty forgiving